# In a junction table, if I need a singular unique identifier and a separate unique composite identifier, which should be the primary key?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

My junction table requires a unique singular identifier as well as another separate unique composite identifier made of foreign keys to two tables with a many-to-many relationship. Other questions seem to address only when one or the other is needed.

I have:

APPLICATION table - holds information regarding a type of application

```
- APPLICATION_ID NUMBER(38) PK
```

RESPONDENT table - holds information on a user

```
- RESPONDENT_ID NUMBER(38) PK
```

APPLICATION_INSTANCE junction table - holds information regarding a particular user filling out a particular application

```
- APPLICATION_INSTANCE_ID NUMBER(38) unique (PK?)
- APPLICATION_ID NUMBER(38) FK (PFK?)
- RESPONDENT_ID NUMBER(38) FK (PFK?)
```

Use cases:

```
1. A respondent can only fill out one application of each type
2. APPLICATION_INSTANCE also holds information like the status of an application and date submitted
3. Must be able to query knowing only the APPLICATION_INSTANCE_ID
4. MUST be able to find all applications of a given application type efficiently
5. MUST be able to find all applications of a given respondent efficiently
```

I see two options (I'm leaning towards the first):

```
1. make APPLICATION_INSTANCE_ID PK and enforce a unique constraint between APPLICATION_ID and RESPONDENT_ID 
2. make APPLICATION_ID and RESPONDENT_ID a composite PK and make a unique index on APPLICATION_INSTANCE_ID
```

Which option gives better performance(query speed) when? Is there any significant difference? Is there a better way?

Comment: It doesn't matter. Both are not null and unique. Which of the two you call the primary key or if any of them at all, is merely a matter of personal preference, it has no additional meaning actually. When working with surrogate keys, it's common, however, to make these the tables' primary keys. For `APPLICATION_INSTANCE` you've created the surrogate key `APPLICATION_INSTANCE_ID`, so you would make this the table's primary key.

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner Thanks, I have a working knowledge of sql but don't always know best practices and more subtle nuances if they exist.

Answer (score 1):

In general, I would make the *single* identifier the primary key and declare the pair to be unique.

A junction table can represent an entity as well as a relationship.  For instance, a "purchase" is a junction table that might combine a "customer" and a "product" but have its own attributes.

As you describe this, you have such an entity.  The entity has two really important attributes (the application and the respondent).  These attributes have a really important property (they are jointly unique), so they should be declared `unique`.

Then, if the relationship is being referred to elsewhere, you would use primary key for the foreign key relationship -- and this will be the single column.

From what you describe, I would suggest:

- Primary key:  `application_instance_id`
- Unique:  `(respondent_id, application_id)`
- Index: `(application_id)`

The third index may not be necessary because Oracle supports skip-scans in indexes.  You might want to test to see if the performance is acceptable without the index.

Comment: IF cascade delete on the FK to Application is enabled, the index is probably required.  See eg https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:292016138754